# Determine $p$ such that $u(x,y)=1-\max\{|x|,|y|\}\in W^{1,p}((-1,1)\times(-1,1))$

Tags: sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory, weak-derivatives

> Let $\Omega$ be the open square $(-1,1)^2\subset\mathbb{R}^2$, $u\in L^1(\Omega)$ such that for each $(x,y)\in\Omega$, $u(x,y)=1-\max\{|x|,|y|\}$.
> Determine the weak gradient of $u$ and find $p$ such that $u\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$.

Given $\phi\in\mathcal{D}(\Omega)$, I need to compute separately weak $\partial_xu$ and weak $\partial_yu$:
$$\langle\partial_xu,\phi\rangle = -\langle u,\partial_x\phi\rangle = -\int_\Omega \left(1-\max\{|x|,|y|\}\right)\partial_x\phi\,dx\,dy.$$
I can split the domain $\Omega$ in $$\begin{aligned}
A&=\{(x,y)\in\Omega:y>|x|\}, &B&=\{(x,y)\in\Omega:x>|y|\},\\
C&=\{(x,y)\in\Omega:y<-|x|\}, &D&=\{(x,y)\in\Omega:x<-|y|\},
\end{aligned}$$
but I'm having difficulties in integrating by parts.

---

Following the suggestion in the comments to simply use Fubini-Tonelli's Theorem (since $u\,\partial_x\phi\in L^1(\Omega)$):

$$
\int_\Omega u(x,y)\partial_x\phi(x,y)\,dx\,dy = \int_{-1}^1\underbrace{\int_{-1}^1u(x,y)\partial_x\phi(x,y)\,dx}_{\displaystyle I(y)}\,dy \\
\begin{aligned}
I(y) &= \int_{-1}^1(1-\max\{|x|,|y|\})\partial_x\phi(x,y)\,dx = \dots \\
&= -\int_{-1}^{-|y|}\phi(x,y)\,dx + \int_{|y|}^1\phi(x,y)\,dx \\
&= \int_{-1}^1\left[\pmb{1}_{(|y|,1)}(x)-\pmb{1}_{(-1,|y|)}(x)\right]\phi(x,y)\,dx,
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\pmb{1}_S$ is the indicator function of the set $S$. So we simply have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\langle\partial_x u,\phi\rangle &= -\int_\Omega u(x,y)\partial_x\phi(x,y)\,dx\,dy \\
&= -\int_\Omega\left[-\pmb{1}_D+\pmb{1}_B\right]\phi\,dx\,dy = \int_\Omega\left[\pmb{1}_D-\pmb{1}_B\right]\phi\,dx\,dy
\end{aligned}
$$
and thus the weak partial $x$-derivative of $u$ would be $\pmb{1}_D-\pmb{1}_B$. Is that correct?

Comment: Can you post your attempt at integrating by parts? The thing to keep in mind is that the normal derivatives on parts that share a boundary line will will have opposite directions, and thus cancel out.

Comment: The problem I'm facing is at the beginning. Evans' PDE book [appendix C.2, page 627] shows the integrating by parts formula in the case of $\partial\Omega\in\mathcal{C}^1$, which is not this case. Are there other sources I could look into?

Comment: The integration by parts formula works also in the case of Lipschitz boundaries (which these ones are), but in this particular case you can work out the proof by "explicitly" computing the integrals: Parametrize the boundaries and use Fubini's theorem to compute the integrals in the $x$ and $y$ directions.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion regarding the Fubini's Theorem, @Jose27
I have updated my question.

Comment: That looks correct, as long as you've correctly justified the vanishing of the integral from $-|y|$ to $|y|$ for instance.

Comment: When $x<|y|$, $u(x,y)=1-|y|$ and its partial $x$-derivative is $0$. The border terms are $0$ since $\phi$ is supported in $\Omega$. As for the second question, $u$ is trivially in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ for each $p\in[1,\infty]$ due to $\Omega$ being bounded and $\nabla u\in(L^1(\Omega))^2$.

Comment: I think you mean $\nabla u\in (L^\infty(\Omega))^2$, but yes you're correct.